# Run Galfit in terminal

Tags: command-line, executable

I'm trying to run a program called Galfit. I want to be able to just type `galfit` in the terminal and for it to run (then add switches and commands etc like `galfit <input file>`)

I've tried putting the program in `/usr/local/bin/` and `/opt/`, but this doesn't work. I don't know how to make it respond to the command `galfit`!

It seems like it should be so simple. I've followed this [guide](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) to do something similar with Sublime Text 2 and it worked. So, why not for Galfit?

Comment: How do you installed such a program? Is it the file marked as executable? Does `echo $PATH` lists `/usr/local/bin`, as it should do?

Comment: Yes, it is listed in PATH. I haven't 'installed' anything.

Answer (score 1):

OP posted:

> Solved by adding the path of `galfit` to the PATH.